# CSS positioning at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Is it somehow possible to have a DIV container always positioned at the end of a page and if the page content is not filling up the window to the bottom, the DIV is fixed at the window bottom?

See the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4g98muw/

The bottom of the ".bottom" div is not allowed to move higher than the bottom of the window. With Javascript I could give the ".bottom"-DIV postion:fixed; bottom:0; if I have just a little text and if I have lots of text I could remove that.

Is there a trick without Javascript?

```css
.bottom {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

  <div class="bottom">
    bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put it on the bottom of the page code and use `clear:both` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

  <div class="bottom">
    bottom
  </div>
</div>

.main{
   min-height:600px;
   position:relative;
}
.bottom {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```